# Manhwa/Manhua of a female lead who is reincarnated as a witch and eats human beings to keep young and the ML remembers all his previous lives

Tags: story-identification, manga

I can't remember the name but I from what I remember that the FL woke up to have already eaten a few human beings maybe children as well but the ML was still alive barely. He promises himself he was going to get his revenge since he remembers all the times the FL had killed him but the FL in her old life used to work with kids (not 100% on that one) so she is nice to him and eventually uses her magic to become a kid to go to a school with the actual leads of the original story.

The FL was either a witch or demon.. she also had a group of like demons/witches who followed her not so big like 3-4 people until she disbanded it so they could be better people while she went to school.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: @LogicDictates I want to say it was red like a fiery red

Comment: Any idea when you read this?

Comment: @qazmlpok a few months ago… definitely a few months before New Years.

Comment: Just to confirm - the FL is the main character, the protagonist, correct? And she suddenly wakes up, so this is definitely a reincarnation or isekai story? Do you recall if she explicitly wakes up in a novel or game? She ate the ML multiple times - he is immortal or regenerating, or does she eat him over multiple lifetimes? Is she an immortal? How graphic is the human-eating? Is this likely a grotesque or horror story, or does it all happen off-screen?

Comment: @qazmlpok yes she’s the mc and def a isekai. She eats the ML multiple times but it just seems that everytime she eats him he goes back in time to relive the same situation. She’s immortal and she keeps herself young by eating the kids and it’s not grotesque it’s mentioned but you don’t see horrible scenes just piles of dead bodies basically. I want to say it’s a novel.

Comment: @Chimex A novel as in a light novel or web novel, correct? You had tagged it as manga, so I was expecting this to be a comic. And it'd likely be originally Korean or Chinese originally?

Comment: @qazmlpok oh no I thought you meant if she reincarnated into a novel or otome game.. it’s a webtoon and it’s either Korean or Chinese, im between the both because it has enough sus scenes to be Chinese but the art style and the way it’s written definitely isn’t.

Answer (score 2):

I think the name was *[The Villainess Refuses to Court (or Flirt with) the Male Lead](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-villainess-refuses-to-court-the-male-lead)* by Kuri.

[image: Front cover of The Villainess Refuses to Court (or Flirt with) the Male Lead]

> Transmigrating as the villainess of a cliché imperial manhua isn't scary, what's scary is that the male leads are all children! Not only do I have to take care of children, but I'm also being courted by one of them and being called "wife"!

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE. This looks like commentary on the question rather than an answer at first glance. You can improve your answer by [edit]ing in _why_ you think this is what the OP is looking for. Any matching details, a synopsis, cover image would help. See [answer] for some helpful tips

Comment: @DavidW - I also thought so at first, but this _is_ an answer, just in need of some details. The proposed manga is "_The Villainess Refuses to Court the Male Lead_", and the first panel does contain a female lead, who worked with children, and someone who was "transmigrated [...] into someone who uses children as ingredients".

Comment: @fez  Arg.  I hate when the title just looks like some random sentence.

Comment: Isekai has gotten so self-aware. Now they even advertise that they are cliche in the cover blurb. Not that there are not some decent ones: Pokémon Legends Arceus was a cut above the usual isekai.

Comment: Ah, a review that says that the manga *may* contain pedophilia and child abuse (perhaps on the part of the nominal hero). That sounds like a charming story.

Comment: But I guess who needs a richly characterized setting like *Fullmetal Alchemist* or something when you can just have an everperson office worker transmigrate into a thin pastiche of a medieval European fantasy/romance game/European fantasy romance game and toss in some dubious positive depictions of sexual violence to ensure that it will have a captive audience regardless of the quality of the plot?